# How is struts finding css files?

Tags: java, css, jsp, struts2, freemarker

I'm working with struts 2. In my JSP I have a `<s:head />` tag. Somhow this triggers this css links to be inserted into the final HTML file:

```
<link href="/app/styles/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link href="/app/styles/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flick/jquery-ui-1.10.0.xyz.min.css" />
```

How does struts know about this files? How can I add other CSS files or change them?

Comment: Forgot about the other themes. I only use the `simple` one, handling the HTML by myself, and those files are not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a nasty one. After all I discovered that the application is using sitemesh **and** uses the `<s:head>` tag in the final jsp. This means the first 3 CSS files are comming fromt the sitemesh template, the `struts/xhtml/styles.css` is comming from the xhtml fremarker template.

Answer (score 2):

Struts UI tags generate HTML content via executing freemarker templates. The default templates are found in the core package under the `/template` folder. The default template for the `head` tag is `head.ftl`.

There are several files one per theme. Corresponding template is used by selecting a theme for your tag, page, or application. See more about [Selecting Themes](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/selecting-themes.html).

If you want to change some templates you need to create a template folder and specify it as `templateDir`. Then copy/paste your `head.ftl` to this folder under the corresponding theme, e.g.  `/template/xhtml/head.ftl`. Now, when [template is loading](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/template-loading.html) it will search this folder for the template overridden by you.

Another solution is possible to by [extending an existed theme](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/extending-themes.html#ExtendingThemes-ExtendinganExistingTheme). You can choose whatever applicable to you.

Comment: I checked the freemarker templates. There's nothing telling me why it's using exactly 3 three css files and what I have to do to change them.

Comment: It's using as many times as used `link` tag in those FTLs. You can post your templates code to see what and how many times css is linked.

Comment: Im using the xhtml theme which includes `struts/xhtml/styles.css`. Actually I just found this as well in the resulting HTML. But that still does not explain where the other CSS files are comming from.

Comment: Check your project files for `.ftl` files or other templates like velocity templates (`.vm`).

Comment: There are no `.ftl` files.

Comment: Do you have a template folder, if yes what is inside it?