# Prevent struts 2 from autogenerating id

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

The following element  is created with id attribute in struts 2.

```
<s:select style="min-width:7.5em;max-width:15.5em;" class="form-control"  headerKey="SELECT" headerValue="SELECT" list="costCenters" required="true" name="costCenter" />
```

I don't want the id because later I'll 'jquery.clone()' it.

Current output:

```
 <select name="costCenter" id="formName_costCenter" class="form-control" style="min-width:7.5em;max-width:15.5em;" required="true">
<option value="SELECT" selected="selected">SELECT</option>
<option value="COST CENTER 1">COST CENTER 1</option>
<option value="COST CENTER 2">COST CENTER 2</option>
</select>
```

Desired:

```
 <select name="costCenter" class="form-control" style="min-width:7.5em;max-width:15.5em;" required="true">
<option value="SELECT" selected="selected">SELECT</option>
<option value="COST CENTER 1">COST CENTER 1</option>
<option value="COST CENTER 2">COST CENTER 2</option>
</select>
```

struts.xml has

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"/>
```

Comment: Do you want to change a template?

Comment: Don’t understand what you mean by changing the template. I want to prevent struts from generating id attribute.

Comment: you can't do it with the default template loading but there's a workaround, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts `id` attribute is autogenerated, but you can set the `id` attribute manually. The id attribute for [`<s:select>`](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html) tag means HTML `id` attribute.

You can't prevent Struts from generating `id` attribute unless you change the template that renders HTML from `<s:select>` tag. You can read more about [Themes and Templates](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/themes-and-templates.html) in the Tag Developer's Guide. You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23610196/573032) answer to help understand Struts UI tags.

Another way to remove attribute from the element using jQuery is [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) function.

```
$("#formName_costCenter").removeAttr("id");
```

Comment: Thanks. If there’s no way to tell struts not to add Id attribute, I’ll be using your logic to remove the id. So sad struts forces this