# Error while upgrade to Struts 6 with struts jquery plugin

Tags: struts2, freemarker, struts2-jquery

We have upgraded to `Struts 6.0.0`. The project `Struts 2 jquery plugin version 4.0.3`.
When loading a page we face this error:

```
Could not load the FreeMarker template named 'div':
Attempted: /template/jquery/div.ftl
Attempted: /template/xhtml/div.ftl
Attempted: /template/simple/div.ftl
The TemplateLoader provided by the FreeMarker Configuration was a: org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerThemeTemplateLoader
Could not open template
```

The stack trace cause is:

```
Caused by: freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "template/jquery/div.ftl" in line 22, column 43:
Using ?html (legacy escaping) is not allowed when auto-escaping is on with a markup output format (HTML), to avoid double-escaping mistakes.
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.BuiltIn(FMParser.java:1225)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.PrimaryExpression(FMParser.java:595)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.UnaryExpression(FMParser.java:707)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MultiplicativeExpression(FMParser.java:822)
```

The line 22 in file `template/jquery/div.ftl` is as:

```
<#if parameters.id??> id="${parameters.id?html}"<#rt/></#if>
```

I am not familiar with `Freemaker` and I hope I could find a flag or something to by pass this.

I see the migration guide at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.5+to+6.0.0+migration and also https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/tag-syntax#escaping-body-of-a-tag but could not find the issue

I try to set `struts.ui.escapeHtmlBody` this in `struts.xml` but it did not help.

Comment: The jQuery plugin is not compatible w/ Struts 6. Keep in mind the jQuery plugin is not an official Struts plugin so support may lag behind.

Comment: If you have problems with freemarker, first I would check its version.

Comment: @RomanC thanks. I find the the freemaker version in both `Struts 2.5.30` and `Struts 6.0.0` is `Freemaker 2.3.31`.

Comment: The freemarker version should be less than 2.3.24 to get rid of autoescaping feature which I think is not supported by the old plugin. Otherwise you have to use your own templates. How to load custom templates you can find by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23610196/573032) answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery, for struts 6.0 the struts jQuery plugin 6.0 must be used.

[image]

Changing below in `pom.xml` fix it

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-grid-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-datatables-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-richtext-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-tree-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```